# sample size of a linear regression in R?

Tags: r, regression, linear

how can i see the sample size of a linear regression? i would like to know a demand, which gives me the samplesize. I did some linear regression and the variables contains different samplesizes. Thank you.

Comment: To the extent that this is a question about R-coding rather than statistics it's potentially [off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but it sounds like there's potentially a misunderstanding of a statistical issue here; the question is however not clear enough to be quite sure what you mean. Please give more details of your situation

Answer (score 1):

If there's no missing data, then I presume that you could simply get the sample size from your data frame.

If there is missing data, then the sample size will depend on how you are handling it (e.g., whether you delete entire cases with missing data, whether you impute the values).